# C++ - can I create a member of another class and use it in a constructor?

Tags: c++, oop

So I have two classes - one for a specific Player and one for a Team for players.

```
Player(string line){
    string write;
    stringstream line1(line);
    int i = 0;
    while (getline(line1, write, ';')){
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                name = write;
                i++;
                break;
            case 1:
                surname = write;
                i++;
                break;
            case 2:
                skills[0] = write;
                i++;
                break;
            case 3:
                skills[1] = write;
                i++;
                break;
            case 4:
                skills[2] = write;
                i++;
                break;
            case 5:
                skills[3] = write;
                i++;
                break;
            case 6:
                skills[4] = write;
                i++;
                break;
            case 7:
                age = stoi(write);
                i++;
                break;
            case 8:
                height = stoi(write);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The Player class has a constructor that takes a string with all of parameters and sets them all. It works.
What I want to accomplish is be able to pass a file containing some lines (fstream type) to a constructor of Team class and make a team of Players specified in the file. This is what I tought of:

```
Team(fstream file){
    string one;
    while (getline(file, one))
        Player asdf = (one);
        addPlayer(asdf);
}
```

Use of undeclared identifier 'asdf' is all I get from this. Could someone guide me to the right approach?

Comment: `Player asdf(one);`.

Comment: Are you sure the header containing the definition of `Player` has been included?

Comment: It all was because of a missing bracket. Sorry about that! :(. Also - is Player asdf(one); just a different notation or actually differs?

Comment: @PeteBecker Once again, answers do not belong in the comments where they cannot be peer reviewed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit -- pointing out the typo before closing a question as merely a typo is a courtesy, not an answer.

Comment: If the courtesy is wrong it cannot be peer reviewed. No answers go in the comments section. In the case of a typo, answering then VTC is fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest that you learn about the SOLID principles of OOP programming. One of these is the Single Responsibility Principle: a class should do one thing only and do it well. In this case, a `Player` should be responsible for storing the details of a player, but should not also parse the data from input. Instead, I suggest that you write an external function which parses all the data and passes them as parameters to the `Player` constructor. Similarly, you can parse a the input and pass a `std::vector<Player>` to the `Team` constructor.

Comment: One advantage is you can more easily deal with errors. Note what happens when there is an error reading the player's name. The while loop will halt, but the `Player` instance will still be constructed without any fields initialized. Worse, if there is an error reading one of the skills, then some of the `Player` fields will be initialized and some won't. It is not a good idea to construct objects in such a partial state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, yes it is possible to create an object in the CTOR and keep it around.  Be aware that by doing this you are allocating memory, and this can cause your constructor to fail. Also, you are passing a local variable to the "AddPlayer" method, which *might* be a problem, depending on how that is implemented.

Without seeing more code, what you have posted looks valid. 
Are both pieces of code in the same source file?  Perhaps you need "#include Player.h" at the top of the file declaring the team.

Comment: Rechecked my code and I was missing a }. Embarrassing. Thanks for assuring me that I was thinking correctly!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: To answer the actual question; you can create an instance of another class within a constructor and then use it however you please.  As a side note, `member` generally refers to variables and functions declared within a class.

The line:

```
Player asdf = (one);
```

Can be changed to:

```
Player asdf(one);
```

Also a word of caution, you are making a copy of `adsf` when you pass it to `addPlayer()`.  That may well be appropriate.  But you do have the option to employ move semantics if that is a better fit.